# Add class to most visible div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a webpage with large horizontal banner images, they are all set to opacity 0.5, I would like to toogle the **.no-opacity** class to the banner that is most visible in the viewport on scroll. How would I achieve this with jQuery?

#### HTML

```
<div class="banner">
  <img src="foo1.png" width="960" height="450" />
</div>
<div class="banner">
  <img src="foo2.png" width="960" height="450"/>
</div>
<div class="banner">
  <img src="foo3.png" width="960" height="450"/>
</div>
<div class="banner">
  <img src="foo4.png" width="960" height="450"/>
</div>
<div class="banner">
  <img src="foo5.png" width="960" height="450"/>
</div>
<div class="banner">
  <img src="foo6.png" width="960" height="450"/>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
  background: #000;
}

.banner {
  opacity: 0.5
}

.no-opacity {
  opacity: 1.0;    
}
```

Comment: "most visible", what do you mean? Most centered in viewport, toppest, bottomest, etc... {sorry for uggly english...} You should be interrested by waypoints plugin.  BTW, where is your attempt, at least post your onscroll handler.

Comment: what is your definition of "most visible" if they are all opacity 0.5 ???

Comment: centered in the window vertical I'm guessing.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing the answer to this. As the window scrolls vertical, the opacity increases to the center, then decreases as it leaves the center. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be close to what you want: <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/zWBmG/)</kbd>

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var winHeight = $(this).height();
    var winBottom = winTop + winHeight

    $('.banner').each(function (index, item) {
        var itemTop = $(item).position().top;
        var itemHeight = $(item).height();
        var itemBottom = itemTop + itemHeight;

        if (itemTop > winTop && itemBottom < winBottom) {
            $(item).addClass('no-opacity');
        } else {
            $(item).removeClass('no-opacity');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300/FF0000/00FFFF.png" width="200" height="300" />
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300/FF7F00/007FFF.png" width="200" height="300" />
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300/FFFF00/0000FF.png" width="200" height="300" />
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300/7FFF00/7F00FF.png" width="200" height="300" />
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300/00FF00/FF00FF.png" width="200" height="300" />
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300/007FFF/FF7F00.png" width="200" height="300" />
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300/0000FF/FFFF00.png" width="200" height="300" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is it. I wouldn't set a class. Adjust an inline style `opacity` relative to position.

Comment: Fixed issue with images above/below highlighted image being highlighted as well... but if the window height is not the same size as the image height, it will not highlight it. Maybe you can give it a whirl?

Comment: Fantastic! Spot on! :)

Comment: Update - How can I make the scrolling work on iPad/touch devices?